# Block standard ftp on a specific port

Tags: server, ftp, sftp

I want to block port 2121 from using standard ftp, but allow sftp. I am using filezilla for ftp. I want to use port 2121 instead of port 21.

I have tried the following command to try to block port 2121 from using ftp, and allow port 2121 to use sftp which in filezilla is ftpes:

```
  iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.2 --dport 21 -j DROP
```

But the above command did not work and I can login to filezilla using ftp and sftp.

Comment: You should not allow plain (unencrypted) FTP in the first place, except for anonymous access. Also, SFTP usually refers to SSH's FTP-like protocol, and not to "regular" FTP over SSL.

Comment: @fkraiem but what if I want to use ftp on a specific port? How can I do that?